# Missing Vertical Line Table

Tags: latex, tabular

I have code for a latex table, but it seems it's missing the right vertical line in my title row. Am I missing something small? Here's my code:

```
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c||} 
 
  \hline
 \textbf{Table Title} \\  [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 \hline
 Col A & Col B & Col C \\ 
 \hline\hline
 1 & 0.39 & 6.16  \\ 
 \hline
 2 & 0.40 & 4.13  \\ 
 \hline
 3 & 0.28 & 0.12 \\
 \hline
 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

and this is the table I get:

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation of the `booktabs` package. vertical lines in tables are not a professional style.

Comment: off-topic: use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment to avoid the additional vertical spacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically talking, the vertical line on the right of the first row does not appear because the table is set to have three cells per row but that first row only has one cell.

The two `&` in the line of code below would separate three cells within that row, allowing the vertical line on the right to show:

```latex
\textbf{Table Title} & & \\ [0.5ex]
```

Anyway, the solution using `multicolumn` shown in the other answer is to be preferred: this command allows the content of the first row to span along the three columns, less likeky influencing the overall width of the table.

Answer (score 2):

As the row of interest spans three columns, you might want to use `\multicolumn` command: `\multicolumn{# of columns}{alignment}{text}`. So try replacing

`\textbf{Table Title} \\  [0.5ex]`

with

`\multicolumn{3}{||l||}{\textbf{Table Title}}\\`